# PyInstaller won't find package metadata

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyproject.toml

I have created a package that uses `importlib.metadata` to obtain the package version:

```
def get_version() -> str:
    """Get the installed version of this pip package.

    Returns:
        str: Version of this pip package.
    """
    return metadata.version("myproj")
```

When I execute the script, the version is obtained and the script works fine.

However, when I try to create an executable with PyInstaller (with `pyinstaller -F --name MyProj --copy-metadata myproj src/myproj/__main__.py`), PyInstaller returns the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/bin/pyinstaller", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(_console_script_run())
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 214, in _console_script_run
    run()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 198, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 69, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 1071, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 1011, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "/workspaces/myproj/MyProj.spec", line 5, in <module>
    datas += copy_metadata('myproj')
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/utils/hooks/__init__.py", line 957, in copy_metadata
    dist = importlib_metadata.distribution(package_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 969, in distribution
    return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 548, in from_name
    raise PackageNotFoundError(name)
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for myproj
```

I have looked for solutions on StackOverflow and all seemed to suggest adding the `--copy-metadata` flag to avoid this issue. But it does not work for me. When I leave out the flag, PyInstaller runs fine, but then, the executable returns the same `importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for myproj`

In case it's relevant: I'm using `pyproject.toml` and `pdm` to obtain the version of my tool:

```
[tool.pdm.version]
source = "scm"
```